# Derive the right k in k-means clustering (including k = 1) in pyspark

Tags: machine-learning, pyspark, k-means, latitude-longitude

I want to check if a clustering would be helpful or not on my coordinates.

I'm dealing with trajectories and want to check if all of them are starting on a same area (the trajectories are different). Thus the aim here is to characterise the most frequent departure points.

However, sometimes there is no need for clustering. I'm using K-means here. I had thought of using the Silhouette Score but I don't see if it is mathematically correct for the case where there is only one cluster. DBScan will not be a good clustering as density are not similar in the clusters I wanted to build.

Would you have an idea to create a kind of check between k=1 and k=3, which would be the best split for my data? I'm dealing here with data with coordinates (latitude/longitude) where the starting point is not 100% fixed but can vary within 2km around a kind of barycentre.

Simple extract with `k=2` :

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
vecAssembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=["lat", "lon"], outputCol="features")
df1= vecAssembler.transform(df)

from pyspark.ml.clustering import KMeans
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import ClusteringEvaluator

# Loads data.
# Trains a k-means model.
kmeans = KMeans().setK(2).setSeed(1)
model = kmeans.fit(df1.select('features'))
# Make predictions
transformed = model.transform(df1)

evaluator = ClusteringEvaluator(predictionCol='prediction', featuresCol='features', \
                                metricName='silhouette', distanceMeasure='squaredEuclidean')
evaluator.evaluate(transformed)
```

Is there a way to compute in pySpark a case with `k=1` ? in order to derive Elbow or gap statistics ?